# Bad clarity using export_fig

Tags: matlab, plot, export

I am using [Export_fig](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) to export figs from matlab, I am getting very good plots generally. But when i add some textboxs and arrows in the fig. the clarity is pathetic.

I use the `-transparent` property, which does not work either.

```
export_fig('path', '-pdf','-transparent')
```

[image]

Anyone knows what is happening here. Normally this works very good, only when the text is added it acts like this way. Not sure if it's a glitch in the code or if i am doing anything wrong.

Note: I added the text and arrows with insert option on the menu bar.

Comment: You might want to look at [PlotPub](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47921-plotpub-publication-quality-graphs-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not set on using Export_fig for other reasons, consider using MATLAB's built-in print function and increase the resolution with the -r attribute

print('path', '-dpdf', '-r300')

where 'path' is the desired 'path\filename.pdf', '-dpdf' sets the file type, and '-r300' sets the resolution to 300 dpi, also try '-r0' for screen resolution, or higher, till you get what you want.

I'm not sure what the '-transparent' argument is used for but there is probably an equivalent you can find in the documentation.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html

Comment: I really liked the fucntion of export_fig which exports the fig in the size of the figure. With print command, the amount of white space around the plot is horrifying.

Comment: It looks like Export_fig has a -q<val> argument that is used to set the pdf compression quality 0 (high compression) to 100 (lossless compression). Try using -q100, not sure what the default is. Also in regards to transparency, it looks like that might not be supported for what you are trying to do. I would recommend reading through the included _README.md_ file, particularly near the end under _known issues_

Comment: I don't see a difference between other plots which worked and this plot. I am just annding `annotations` inside the graph. I am doing this with the help of UI(from insert option) but when i do it with the command `annotation()` it works fine. But adding the annotations by code is very difficult and The way i want it's very very complicated.